# How to check if given Windows XP SP2 dll library is proper one?

Tags: windows, dll, windows-xp, administrator

How to check if given Windows XP SP2 dll library is proper one ? I have to fix some problem with Windows XP SP2 system, where two dll was manualy replaced (not by me): comctl32.dll and wmploc.dll, are there any tools for doing this ? The problem I face is inproper bahaviour of Windows XP Installator (can't install from msi files since replacement of dlls), what can I do except installing system again or installing on other PC and copy dlls from there ? Are there any windows tools for finding proper dll are there any other tools ?

ps. dlls was manually replaced because of objective reasons - former ones have been destroyed

Answer (score 3):

I would first run the [System File Checker](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;310747) to see if Windows can recover correct copies of the DLLs from it's own cache.

Quoting from the above link:

> System File Checker gives an administrator the ability to scan all protected files to verify their versions. If System File Checker discovers that a protected file has been overwritten, it retrieves the correct version of the file from the cache folder (%Systemroot%\System32\Dllcache) or the Windows installation source files, and then replaces the incorrect file.

Comment: No, that isn't off-topic, it's part of normal diagnostic process for cases like this. Someonne reading this discussion in future may find your info helpful

Comment: It seems that System32\Dllcache contain inproper versions of dlls also.

Comment: @Qbik - can you rename the cached versions and recover from an original XP install CD? Then run Windows Update to get SP2 changes? These are very common DLLs so they must be easy to find...

Comment: it seems that files in System32\Dllcache have been actualized and now contain new versions of dlls - inproper ones

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are some websites that provide these DLL's with version manage control.

[DLL Files](http://www.dll-files.com/) is one of them or [DLL Dump](http://www.dlldump.com/)

Comment: I know about sites like this one.